# How to total data based on current date across sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formula

UPDATE: Resolved by moving to Excel. :(

I have a Google spreadsheet that has a page for every week. I currently am using the following custom function to count the total amount of times the name appears across all sheets.

```
function COUNTALLSHEETS(range, countItem, excluded) {
try {
    var count = 0,
        ex = (excluded) ? Trim(excluded.split()) : false;
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
        .getSheets()
        .forEach(function (s) {
            if (ex && ex.indexOf(s.getName()) === -1 || !ex) {
                s.getRange(range)
                    .getValues()
                    .reduce(function (a, b) {
                        return a.concat(b);
                    })
                    .forEach(function (v) {
                        if (v === countItem) count += 1;
                    });
            };
        });
    return count;
} catch (e) {
    throw e.message;
}
}
function Trim(v) {
return v.toString().replace(/^\s\s*/, "")
.replace(/\s\s*$/, "");
}
```

When I run the function using 
`=COUNTALLSHEETS("$A$1:$G$40", A2, "Rosters")`
it returns the value across all sheets except those excluded by the third argument of the function. In this case, the sheet titled 'Rosters' isn't counted.

My problem is that every week, I have to update the sheets that are excluded. I currently have all sheets dated in the future excluded. So instead of the short call to the function earlier, it looks more like

```
=COUNTALLSHEETS("$A$1:$G$40", A2, "Rosters, 5-9Dec, 12-16Dec, ... etc.")
```

Is there any way to modify the code itself or the function call to exclude future sheets automatically? I'm looking to pull the current date, compare it to a sheet title (which I can change to fit a certain format if needed), and exclude any sheets dated in the future.

Please let me know any ideas; if I need to share a copy of the spreadsheet I can.

Comment: If you got all the sheet names; then converted the sheet names to a string that could be converted to a date; and then compared the date to today date would that work?  So, you would get all the sheet names, loop through them, parse the sheet name into a date, compare the date to today's date.  Then have a test for whatever you want, and either process that sheet, or maybe compile a list of sheet names to either include or exclude.

Comment: @SandyGood: That could work. I know Google Sheets has a way to determine if a date is before or after another. I'll just have to dig deeper into the APIs.

Comment: The date comparison can be done inside of the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to regularly access the excluded sheets? What about hiding them, and only counting unhidden sheets? Might keep things more organized/manageable at the same time as solving your problem. Since I don't thoroughly know your use-case, this may not be the right direction, of course.